# TortoiseHg Workbench keep 'searching for changes' forever

Tags: tortoisehg

I was pushing some changes (the size of which is quite small) to the remote server using TortoiseHg Workbench, the output log at the bottom displayed 'searching for changes'. And it just stayed there forever..When I tried to close the window or cancel the command, there's a message displaying at the above 'sync command already running'.

When I forced to close Tortoise through windows task manager and restarted, I saw the changes are indeed pushed...

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Has happened to me when also trying to pull some changes. I think my internet connection dropped out in the process of accessing a remote server and tortoisehg hung for some reason.

Comment: facing the same Issue.. can somebody help on this...

Comment: it disappeared for me once my push was completed